# RadGrid batch edit original value blank validation exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid using BatchEdit mode. The automated validation is working fine, but I want to program in an exception: blank values are not allowed for fields, but the database is full of records with existing blank values. I want the validation to accept a blank value if the existing record already has a blank value.

Here is my validation method. Note that the attribute `OriginalValue` doesn't exist; it's part of my trying to find the original value, but adding it turned out to be problematic.

```js
        function BlankFieldValidator(sender, args) {
            if (args.Value.length == 0) {
                if (sender.getAttribute("OriginalValue").length != 0) {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

In debugging the page, I can examine the `sender` and `args` objects, but I see nothing that contains the original value in it. I conclude it must be in the Telerik data structure somewhere, since one can still click `Cancel Changes` to revert all changes to the RadGrid.

What is a good method for retrieving the original value to compare to the edited value?

Comment: Infact you can get old-values (OriginalValue) in `OnBatchEditCellValueChanged` or `OnBatchEditCellValueChanging` events using `get_cellValue` for edited-value and `get_editorValue` for  OriginalValue. But this will not solve your problem because these events fire after validation. I think it's better to use two separate validations for insert and update modes using templates.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh I have found those methods and retrieved the original and edited values. I'm trying to work out a way to ensure they always get executed without any weird UI issues. But using that method would mean I don't use the built-in validation, which is, of course, an option. I just think it's a kludgy solution which might be more difficult to debug in the future.

Comment: Using built-in validator requires to somehow detect the radgrid state at `batcheditopened` event (insert or update) and then disable (or edit the behavior) of the validator according to the state. I don't think it is possible (at least easily) or is a straightforward process. This is a useful question which demands more attention.